# How to create global objects in MongoDB's V8 engine to be accessible via db.eval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to use [MongoDB server-side JavaScript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/) in my nodejs/node-mongodb-native project and just interested how could I save my custom functions in global context of MongoDB and get access to them from `db.eval` script?

Let's say I have the following unit function:

```
var myDocumentUtils = {
    doStuff: function (doc) {
       // do stuff with doc ...
       return doc;      
    }
}
```

And I have the following JavaScript function stored in `db.system.js` collection:

```
function processDocument (id) {
    var doc = db.myCollection.findOne({ _id : ObjectId(id)});

    doc = myDocumentUtils.doStuff(doc);   // need access to global myDocumentUtils object     
    db.myCollection.save(doc);

    return doc;
};
```

I execute `processDocument` function from my nodejs application like the following:

```
db.eval('processDocument(54382cb3233283cd3331ca1d)', function (err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;       
});
```

So my question is how to save `myDocumentUtils` in global MongoDB V8 context to be accessible in db.eval function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the second parameter to `processDocument` as below:

```
function processDocument (id, myDocumentUtils) {
    var doc = db.myCollection.findOne({ _id : ObjectId(id)});

    doc = myDocumentUtils.doStuff(doc);   // need access to global myDocumentUtils object     
    db.myCollection.save(doc);

    return doc;
};
```

Then write `db.eval()` like this way:

```
db.eval(function() {
    return processDocument.apply(this, arguments);
}, "54382cb3233283cd3331ca1d", myDocumentUtils);
```

For your environment, you can add the call back just behind the last parameter **myDocumentUtils**.

---

**APPEND ---------------------**

store below tow functions into `db.system.js` :

```
function getMyDocumentUtils() {
    return myDocumentUtils = {
            doStuff: function (doc) {
               // do stuff with doc ...
               return doc;      
            }
        };
}

function processDocument (id) {
    var doc = db.myCollection.findOne({ _id : ObjectId(id)});

    var myDocumentUtils = getMyDocumentUtils(); // added line

    doc = myDocumentUtils.doStuff(doc);   // need access to global myDocumentUtils object     
    db.myCollection.save(doc);

    return doc;
};
```

Then call `db.eval()` as your original style.

Comment: thanks for the response but I can't pass JavaScript object to eval functions because I use nodejs. Is there any solutions yet?

Comment: @Erik, as you are able to store `processDocument` into database, could you also store another function used to return `myDocumentUtils`? This function can be called by `processDocument`.

Comment: could you provide some example please because I little don't understand your suggestion :(

Comment: @Wizardt Thanks you. I do understand your advice and this very cool for me. As I also understand getMyDocumentUtils returns function that evaluates on every call? It it possible to evaluate this function one for performance reasons?

Comment: Can I store two javascript functions in `db.system.js`?

Comment: @Erik, if you need to call `getMyDocumentUtils` frequently, it will be evaluated every time. To avoid this situation, could you write and store function `doStuff()` directly? I mean you can call `doStuff()` directly from `processDocument()`.

Comment: @Erik, you can store any JS function into `db.system.js` by `db.system.js.insert({_id:"functionName", value:<function>})`. And they are global.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So if I will store `db.system.js.insert({_id:"functionName1", value:<function>})` and `db.system.js.insert({_id:"functionName2", value:<function>})` in separate documents, they are accessible for each other?